# SQL Query to find details of person having 3 transaction in a day

Tags: sql

There are 3 Tables: Person, Account, Deposit

**PERSON** ( ***PID***, PName)

```
PID  PNAME
''''''''''
1    King
2    Harry
3    Sams
```

**Account** ( ***Ano***, Amount, *PID*) [Here **PID** is Foriegn Key]

```
........................
Ano      Amount      PID
""""""""""""""""""""""""
A1       10000        1
A2       25000        2
A3       10000        3
```

**DEPOSIT** ( ***TID*** , *Ano*, Amount, Tdate )  [Here **Ano** is Foriegn Key]

```
........................................
Tid        Ano        Amount     Tdate
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
T1         1          2000     20-Jan-98
T2         2          5000     15-Sep-91
T3         2          15000    15-Sep-91
T4         1          5000     12-Jun-12
T5         1          500      12-Jun-12
T6         1          1000     12-Jun-12
T7         3          9000     24-Sep-16
T8         1          1500     21-Aug-96
T9         2          5000     25-Sep-99
T10        3          1000     15-Dec-94
```

I have to Show details of those persons who have done 3 transactions in a day. So according to the given details, Output should be :

```
PID     PName
"""""""""""""
 1      King
"""""""""""""
```

Note - Because Person (ID=1, Name=King) has done 3 Transactions in A Single day.

I Have Solved It Now.

```
SELECT * FROM Person 
WHERE PID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT PID 
    FROM ACCOUNT 
    WHERE ANO IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ANo 
        FROM DEPOSIT
        GROUP BY ANO,TDATE 
        Having Count(ANO)=3)
    );


PID     PName
"""""""""""""
 1      King
"""""""""""""
```

Comment: Have you tried using `HAVING`? http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_group_by_having.htm

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: ok, i will keep it in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in order to find the details of people who perform 3 transactions a day, you would need to change your query to include the date in the count as follows:

```
SELECT ANo,Tdate, count(*) as transcation_per_day 
FROM Deposit 
Group BY ANO,Tdate;
```

That will give you a table of the number of transactions per PID per day. You would simply then need to exclude anything less than 3 transactions, and then join it to the person table to get their details:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.PID,P.PNAME
FROM PERSON as P
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT ANo,Tdate, count(*) as transcation_per_day 
FROM Deposit 
GROUP BY ANO,Tdate
HAVING transcation_per_day>=3
) as C
ON P.PID = C.ANO
```

Note: I added in distinct in order to remove duplicate PIDs in case you have a person who has 3 transactions over multiple days.

Comment: Thanks For helping , I Did it with  the help of your reference.. Now my query is running Successfully..

Answer (score 0):

Join the Tables by POD and use GROUP BY + HABING

> ```
> CREATE TABLE DEPOSIT 
>     (`Tid` varchar(3), `Ano` int, `Amount` int, `Tdate` varchar(9))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO DEPOSIT 
>     (`Tid`, `Ano`, `Amount`, `Tdate`)
> VALUES
>     ('T1', 1, 2000, '20-Jan-98'),
>     ('T2', 2, 5000, '15-Sep-91'),
>     ('T3', 2, 15000, '15-Sep-91'),
>     ('T4', 1, 5000, '12-Jun-12'),
>     ('T5', 1, 500, '12-Jun-12'),
>     ('T6', 1, 1000, '12-Jun-12'),
>     ('T7', 3, 9000, '24-Sep-16'),
>     ('T8', 1, 1500, '21-Aug-96'),
>     ('T9', 2, 5000, '25-Sep-99'),
>     ('T10', 3, 1000, '15-Dec-94')
> ;
> ```

> 

> ```
> CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT 
>     (`Ano` varchar(2), `Amount` int, `PID` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO ACCOUNT 
>     (`Ano`, `Amount`, `PID`)
> VALUES
>     ('A1', 10000, 1),
>     ('A2', 25000, 2),
>     ('A3', 10000, 3)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PERSON
>     (`PID` int, `PNAME` varchar(5))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO PERSON
>     (`PID`, `PNAME`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'King'),
>     (2, 'Harry'),
>     (3, 'Sams')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT  d.Ano, p.PNAME
> FROM DEPOSIT d INNER JOIN ACCOUNT a ON d.Ano = a.PID
> INNER JOIN PERSON p ON a.PID = p.PID
> GROUP BY d.Ano, p.PNAME, d.`Tdate`
> HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
> ```
>
> ```
> Ano | PNAME
> --: | :----
>   1 | King
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3024415f10057543859080f1b22ba93d)*

Comment: In this line                                                                                                                            FROM DEPOSIT d INNER JOIN ACCOUNT a ON d.Ano = a.PID   , How Ano ( Account No) Can be matched with PID( Person ID) ?

Comment: i fist hat d.Ano p.Ano but that doesn't fit, besides the other answer uses teh same logic. BBecause there3 is no other linking column And mine is faster anyway...

Comment: Thanks For reference